# Separating a string by space and storing it in an array of pointers

Tags: c

[image]
My program takes in a string and I break the string into words based on a space, I store the words in an array of pointers. However for some reason it is not separating the words into the appropriate index. In this example and the picture below the text "suspend 0", token[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO9uy.png) should correspond to 0 however it corresponds to "end"

```
int main(){
    int ch ,n= 1;
    int i = 0;
    char str[512], *token[5], *act_token;
    while(1){

            printf("Enter text: ");
            while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
                    str[i++] = ch;
            str[i] = '\0';
            i = 0;

            printf("string: %s\n", str);

            int spaces = 0;
            for(int counter  = 0; counter < strlen(str) + 1; counter++){
                    if(str[counter] == ' '){
                            spaces++;
                    }
            }
            printf("Spaces: %d\n", spaces);
            strtok(str, " ");
            while(n <= spaces && (act_token = strtok(NULL, " "))){
                    token[n] = act_token;
                    n++;

            }
            token[n] = NULL;
    //      printf("token[1]: %s\n", token[1]);
            for(int x = 1; x < spaces+1; x++){
                    printf("token[%d]: %s\n", x, token[x]);

            }
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this example and the picture below the text "suspend 0", token1 should correspond to 0 however it corresponds to "end"

That'a because (most likely) your index `n`, which is for some reason initiated to 1 (why not 0?) outside the `while` loop is not reset at the end of each `while` loop iteration...

Try this:

```
        while(n <= spaces && (act_token = strtok(NULL, " "))){
                token[n] = act_token;
                n++;

        }
        token[n] = NULL;
        n = 1; <-- *** add this line ***
//      printf("token[1]: %s\n", token[1]);
        for(int x = 1; x < spaces+1; x++){
                printf("token[%d]: %s\n", x, token[x]);

        }
```

*NOTE1*: You could eliminate all those search loops if you checked each char during the input process inside `while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')`. Anyway you collect the input char by char, so check it's value and count the spaces + split the words.

*NOTE2*: You are creating arrays of fixed size (for which is better to use `define`s) but you never check for the input not to exceed the limits of those arrays.

Comment: I set n =1 becasue I don't want the first word. This program is just a samller version of a bigger version I'm working on

Comment: @pennyBoy Did setting `n=1` inside the while loop (as I wrote in the answer) helped resolving this issue? (Also see my recent notes in the answer)